# Poor query performance i Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, galera

I have recently moved a production system from a single MySQL instance to a Galera Cluster with three nodes. Everything seems to be working fine, but for SELECT queries; the query performance has since the move dropped drastically and it is now on the unbearable side.

Anyone got any performance tuning tips for Galera? I am a total neophyte on Galera and the setup I have made is probably the simplest there is.

This is the Galera part of the my.cnf file:

```
# Galera
wsrep_provider        =/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address    ="gcomm:// 213.179.3.90, 213.179.3.91, 213.179.3.92"
wsrep_sst_method    =rsync
wsrep_cluster_name    =galera_cluster
binlog_format        =ROW
default_storage_engine    =InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
```

and here is one query that takes forever:

```
SELECT
    r.customerid,
    r.operator,
    r.account,
    CAST(r.requesttype AS char),
    CAST(SUM(r.nofsms) AS char),
    COALESCE(r.subid1, ''),
    COALESCE(r.subid2, ''),
    COALESCE(r.subid3, '')
FROM
    `smspro`.`smspro_cc_result` r
INNER JOIN smspro.smspro_customer sc ON sc.customerid = r.customerid
    AND sc.smsproinvoice = 0
WHERE
    r.status = 0
        AND r.timestamp >= '2016-05-25'
        AND r.timestamp < '2016-06-25'
        AND r.requesttype IN (1 , 2, 4, 5)
GROUP BY r.customerid , r.operator , r.account , r.requesttype , r.subid1 , r.subid2 , r.subid3
ORDER BY r.customerid , r.operator , r.account , r.requesttype , r.subid1 , r.subid2 , r.subid3
```

And some stats

```
mysql> select count(*) from smspro_cc_result;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  9170870 |
+----------+

mysql> show index from smspro_cc_result;
+------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| smspro_cc_result |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | smsproid    | A         |     8825169 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| smspro_cc_result |          1 | idx_sms_req_1 |            1 | customerid  | A         |       14757 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| smspro_cc_result |          1 | idx_sms_req_2 |            1 | timestamp   | A         |     4412584 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| smspro_cc_result |          1 | idx_sms_req_3 |            1 | customerid  | A         |       18233 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| smspro_cc_result |          1 | idx_sms_req_3 |            2 | msisdn      | A         |     8825169 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| smspro_cc_result |          1 | idx_sms_req_3 |            3 | timestamp   | A         |     8825169 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| smspro_cc_result |          1 | idx_sms_req_5 |            1 | msisdn      | A         |     8825169 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Did I forget anything or is all background material here?

Comment: "Query" meaning `SELECT` or all queries?

Comment: SELECT is the problem, as far as I know. There seems to be no problems with the system generating data; it is the reporting that has taken a big hit, performancewise.

Comment: Are you CPU bound or disk bound?  Are these machines comparable to the former server?  ...particularly with regard to disk performance and memory, but also type and number of cores?  Is the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` comparable?

Answer (score 2):

[*My Tips*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/tips-on-converting-to-galera/).

If the 3 nodes are geographically spread around, latency is costly on `COMMIT`.

Are you comparing to a single server?  Or a Replication setup?  Or something else?  Is the Client in the server with one of the nodes?  Is a load-balancer or Proxy involved?

If you have not re-tuned several InnoDB settings, Galera will not perform optimally.  Let's see your config file.  (Or post both `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`, plus RAM size.)

What queries are showing a degradation?  Looking at them may help us to focus on the issue and, hopefully, a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for helping a fellow peer

Comment: I am comparing to a single server - I replaced that with a cluster for redundancy. All servers are geographically on the same spot (all virtual, should be added).

Comment: "All virtual"... meaning... they are all running on thr same shared physical hardware and reading from and writing to different directories but on the same disk?   Or three independent servers that happen to be VMs?

Comment: Three servers that are virtual. They have their own disk, network card, etc.

Comment: These are in some Cloud?  Same "availability zone"?

Comment: Have you identified a particular query that is running noticeably slower?

Comment: The same - we rely on a vendor who provides the infrastructure so I assume it is all in one location (possibly in the same rack).

Comment: Let's hope no one trips over the power cord for that rack.  At least Galera will probably repair itself when they come back up.